# Understanding the Proof of l'Hospital's Rule from Stromberg

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

I am reading *An Introduction to Classical Real Analysis* by Karl Stromberg. On pages 180-181 Stromberg gives a proof of l'Hospital's Rule.

[image]
[image]

[image]

I don't understand why he chooses $\beta$ such that $\alpha<\beta<L$. It seems to me that working with an arbitrary $\alpha<L$ is sufficient (If $\alpha\leq z$ for all $\alpha<L$ then $L\leq z$) . Am I missing something?

I know that in PMA (p.109) Rudin does the same thing, but in that case I think it is necessary because he doesn't use limsup and liminf and he needs an open neighborhood of $L$.

Comment: You have a valid point. Proving that $z\geq \alpha$ for all $\alpha <L$ implies $z\geq L$.

Comment: Some textbooks authors themselves try to propagate the false belief that real-analysis is more difficult than most other math subjects.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh So you agree that this is not necessary? I know that in PMA (p.109) Rudin does the same thing, but in that case I think it is necessary because he doesnt use limsup and liminf and he needs an open neighborhood of $L$.

Comment: Yeah this is not necessary and probably this has been copied from some Rudin like source without bothering to understand the exact context. Luckily math is a subject where it is not so difficult to find errors in textbooks.

Comment: Perhaps the author here believes that one needs the strict inequality $z>\alpha$ for all $\alpha<L$ to conclude $z\geq L$. In fact it does not matter whether the inequality is strict or not in many contexts.

Comment: Exactly, it seems like Stromberg insisted to have a strict inequality, although I couldn't find any reason why this must be so. Thanks a lot for your help.